# Trying to add a maintenance page to nginx.... but it doesn't work

Tags: linux, nginx

I have this nginx config for website which has its own web server, that is, nginx is working as a proxy reverse.

Some config parts are omitted:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    [.........];
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  [.........];
  return 301 https://my_website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    [.........];

    location / {
      [.........];
      proxy_redirect  http://localhost:1234 https://my_website.com;
    }

    location /assets/ {
      alias /opt/my_website/assets;
    }
```

Now I'm trying to add a maintenance page:

```
    location / {
      [.........];
      proxy_redirect  http://localhost:1234 https://my_website.com;
    }

    location /assets/ {
      alias /opt/my_website/assets;
    }



  # here it is
  if (-f /opt/my_website/maintenance_on.html) {
      return 503;
    }

    error_page 503 @maintenance;
    location @maintenance {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
    }
```

But it simply doesn't work -- nothing happens when I create the page.

Comment: Have you set a `root` directive? `nginx` needs to know where to find `maintenance.html`.

Comment: @RichardSmith, where should be the root in my case: 1) /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 2) /opt/my_website/html 3) /etc/nginx/sites-available/ 4) somewhere else?

Comment: Where is the file `maintenance.html`?

Comment: @RichardSmith, /opt/my_website/html . Or instead of setting the root, can I provide a full path to maintenance.html?

Comment: when I specify the full path, nothing changes

Answer (score 2):

The `rewrite` directive produces URIs. You need a `root` directive to translate it into a local pathname:

```
location @maintenance {
    root /opt/my_website/html;
    rewrite ^ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: "not found". Note that the file name has "_on" in the end

Comment: The `rewrite` statement was copied from your question.

Comment: why not `^(.*)$`?

Comment: `^` matches the same strings as `^(.*)$`, except with less work. `^` means simply start of a string in regex.